# updating datagridview from many tables

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2015

I have datagridview, that i must fill by 5 tables. I declared SqlCommand and SqlConnection.
After that I use somethine like this:

```
selCommand.Connection = conn;
dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
ad.SelectCommand = selCommand;
ad.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

As a result I have column headers of my query in datagridview, but don't have data.
I tried use this code:

```
selCommand.Connection = conn;
dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataReader dr = selCommand.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(dr);
bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
dr.Close();
```

It was working, but I something change and I can't understand why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable table = null;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Something WHERE Id = @Id";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", YourValue));
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle your exception;   
    }
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```